# Access constant of a class member object doesn't work

Tags: php, static, class-constants

if I try the following example (PHP 5.4) I get the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM), expecting ',' or ';'

```
class a {
    public $p;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->p = new b;
    }
    public function giveout() {
        echo $this->p::c;
    }
}
class b {
    const c = '234';
}
$obj = new a;
$obj->giveout();
```

But why? Isn't it possible to use the double colon and arrow in one expression?
I know I could also use a getter method in class b and then call `$this->p->get()`, but I'd rather like to use the above syntax.

Comment: Ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/keyword.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite

```
echo $this->p::c;
```

to

```
echo $this->p=b::c;
```

and..

```
$a->giveout();
```

to

```
$obj->giveout();
```

### Putting it all together...

```
<?php
class a {
public $p;
public function __construct() {
$this->p = new b;
}
public function giveout() {
echo $this->p=b::c;
}
}
class b {
const c = '234';
}
$obj = new a;
$obj->giveout();
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
234
```

Comment: Sorry the `$a` in my original post was a mistake of mine, it should have been `$obj`, you are right. But wouldn't this syntax override `$this->p` and save the value of `b::c` in it?